# Как получить уведомление о платеже от Яндекс.Касса?

Tags: php, yandex-money

Всем привет. Первый раз связался с Яндекс.Касса API и остановился на [3-ем шаге](https://kassa.yandex.ru/docs/guides/?php#shag-3-dozhdites-uwedomleniq-o-platezhe) и я не понимаю как получить уведомление о платеже, чтобы его подтвердить или отклонить.

Я создал платеж на сайте как в документации, получил с ответа *confirmation_url*, перешёл к оплате на Яндекс.Касса и провел тестовый платёж, оплата успешная, но больше ничего. При нажатии на клавишу "Вернуться в магазин" и возвращении на страницу обратно ничего не происходит и не передаются параметры об плате в ссылке, чтобы хотя-бы получить id платежа для того чтобы потом подтвердить или отклонить платёж.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может быть я что-то опустил или чего-то не понимаю, но надеюсь на вашу помощь. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: как получать (и куда) - это всё описано в документации...   В разделе Настройки укажите URL, по которому Яндекс.Касса будет отправлять уведомления об успешной оплате в вашу систему.
https://yandex.ru/support/checkout/payments/api.html#api__01.